# Find Subelement in JObject of unknown property name

Tags: c#, json

I have the following Json-Structure converted to JObject:

```
{
  "success": false,  
  "errors": {
    "13": {    
      "errorCode": "address missing"
     },
    "4711": {
      "year":1395
    }
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve the value of "errorCode". The problem is that the child under "errors" can be ANY number so I cannot simply use

`jsonDetail.SelectToken("errors.13.errorCode")`

to retrieve the value under "errorCode".

There always is only ONE child that contains "errorCode" but there can be additional children too (which I want to ignore)-

Comment: [`SelectToken` with `JSONPath`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm#SelectTokenJSONPath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the `JObject` using `SelectToken` and a JSONPath expression https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm

In your case you just need this

```cs
var errorCode = jsonDetail.SelectToken("$..errorCode");
```

You can find more detail on JSONPath expressions here https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ (this link was found in Newtonsoft's own documentation)

From the documentation on JSONPath you can see that `$` is for the root object, and the `..` is the recursive descent, so this will recursively search the root object for a child with the token name of `errorCode`